# Why does matrix multiplication need to follow the rule of joined corner marks?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know the matrix multiplication formula must meet  joined corner marks

$
A_{ms} \cdot B_{sn} = C_{mn}
$

but why? why we must follow this rule? how to understand it in terms of linear transformations?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of linear maps, it means that if you have a linear map $f\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^s$ and another linear map $g\colon\Bbb R^{s'}\longrightarrow\Bbb R^m$, then you can consider $g\circ f$ if and only if $s=s'$. If $s\ne s'$, then that composition makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Identify an $m \times n$ matrix $A \in M(m \times n, \mathbb{R})$ as the element $A \in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ defined by $Ae_j = j$th column of $A$. This identification is a vector space isomorphism between $M(m \times n, \mathbb{R})$ and $L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$. Matrix multiplication is defined so that this isomorphism preserves products as well.